# UniqueEntity validation error placed on password field in FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

When I try to register a new User that is supposed to be unique by email, the UniqueEntity constrain works propely, the error though sits on the password field instead of the email field, anyone know why?

User Class:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as FOSUser;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
(...)
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 * (...)
 */
class User extends FOSUser
```

Form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email'))
            ->add('firstName', null, array('label' => 'form.first_name'))
            ->add('lastName', null, array('label' => 'form.last_name'))
            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch'
            ))
    ;
}
```

Form render:

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

And the error, from profiler:

```
**Origin:** first   (the password field)

Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).data.plainPassword.data.second = EMAIL@DOMAIN...
```

Not only the password field is passed the whole user object it seems, it causes the validation of UniqueEntity constraint and I can not "debug down" the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running symfony `2.5.0` - `2.5.2` then this is a bug related to the new validation API. It was [fixed](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/11412) in `2.5.3`

If upgrading is not an option you can work around it by forcing the old validation API in your `config.yml`

```
validation:
    enable_annotations: true
    api: 2.4 # default is auto which sets API 2.5 BC
```

Comment: Well this fixes the thing with context, but now, since I use an email user provider, I have one global error on my form "The username is already used" and a double error on my email/username field "The email is already used This value is already used. "
Thx for the answer